# Option get data from DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have got this table in my Database:

```
**train_information**

train_id
country_id
user_id
train_name
tare_weight
number_of_bogies
number_of_axles
wheel_diameter_min
wheel_diameter_max
```

And then i have 2 .php pages (1 is only for classes)

Selector.php

```
<!--Selector-->
<form name='form' id='selector'>
    <?php
        $selector = $database->selector();
    ?>
        <select onchange= "mySelection()" id ="selector" name="selector">
        <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecteer een trein</option>
    <?php 
        foreach ($selector as $selector) {
            print "<h3>" . $selector['train_id'] . "==" . $selector_id . "</h3>";
            if ($selector['train_id'] == $selector_id) {
                echo "<option value=" . $selector['train_id'] . " selected='selected'> " . $selector['train_name'] . "</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value=" . $selector['train_id'] . "> " . $selector['train_name'] . "</option>";
            } }     
        ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

And then the class.php

```
function selector() {
        $sql = "SELECT train_id, train_name FROM train_information";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

The selector shows the train names in the selection. so that is good.
But i want that when i select it, and press a button like: Select. That it select the information of that selected train and shows it on the page.
And i don't only want to show 1, but if i would like to select a other train after that, it shows both trains information on the page.

How do i do this?

Comment: The script that you submit the form to can do a `SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE train_id = $_POST['selector']` and display the information.

Comment: So in my class.php replace the $sql with it??

Comment: No, this goes into `selector.php` when it's processing the form submission. And your form also needs a Submit button. Unless you're doing this with AJAX, then you need to do that in the AJAX server script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following

Add this Method to class.php

```
function select_train_details($trainId) {
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information where train_id = " . $trainId;
         $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
         $sth->execute();
         return $sth->fetchAll();
     }
```

Add Following to selector.php

```
 <form name='form' id='selector'>
     <?php
     $selector = $database->selector();
     if (isset($_POST['selector'])) {
         $selectorDetail = $database->select_train_details();
     }
     ?>
     <select onchange= "this.form.submit" id ="selector" name="selector">
         <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Selecteer een trein</option>
         <?php
         foreach ($selector as $selector) {
             print "<h3>" . $selector['train_id'] . "==" . $selector_id . "</h3>";
             if ($selector['train_id'] == $selector_id) {
                 echo "<option value=" . $selector['train_id'] . " selected='selected'> " . $selector['train_name'] . "</option>";
             } else {
                 echo "<option value=" . $selector['train_id'] . "> " . $selector['train_name'] . "</option>";
             }
         }
         ?>
     </select> </form> <?php if (isset($selectorDetail)) {
     echo "<pre>";
     $selectorDetail; } ?>
```

Comment: I feel realy stupid, But what do i have to fill in at 'enter code here ?>